# Lines in console not filling up the available space

Tags: c#, console-application

In my program, I am writing out the data from a jagged array into the console (1 array per line) and for better readability, I put a tab after every number but now the lines break after 15 numbers although there would be enough space.

[image: Lines not going to the edge]

And here's the code for printing it:

```
static void PrintAbfüllmengen(int[][] Abf30Tage)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < Abf30Tage.Length; j++)
    {
        if (j % 2 == 0)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < Abf30Tage[j].Length; k++)
        {
            Console.Write(Abf30Tage[j][k] + ",\t");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Any way I can get around that problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems your console has 120 chars width. If we assume max value for your array items is 9999, and space for comma and space, then you can fit 120 / (4 + 2) = 20 numbers in a line. But your arrays have 24 items. You have to expand your console width before writing, and use format `Console.Write("{0,4}, ", Abf30Tage[j][k])`. Or maybe even more complex to skip last comma, like `Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", Abf30Tage[j].Select(x => x.ToString().PadLeft(5))))` instead of the whole `for` loop.

Console is not a good option if you want to have "pretty" view of your data. So either don't try to make it pretty, or change to windows environment, or suffer in the agony that is "I just want to make it pretty in console".